# creating an exception handler in HTML5/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, exception, visual-studio-2012

I am new to the web development world and I would like I am lost in the steps of creating an exception in a java script function

what I want to ideally do is something following the following syntax ...

```
function exceptionhandler (){
     if (x===5)
     {
          //throw an exception
     }
}
```

I found the following tutorial 
http://www.sitepoint.com/exceptional-exception-handling-in-javascript/
But I don t know how to convert the above if statement into a try..catch...finally exception

thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like the place for a `try..catch`, but for throwing an exception. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: what I need it to have a conditional exception , and based on my readings this I understood that the try catch scenario is the one that catches the errors ... you can correct me if I am wrong by all means :)

Comment: Yes, but `try..catch` will catch an exception if it already occurred. A check for equality like `if(x===5)` will never throw an exception.

Comment: @bfavaretto `orly === false` - `ReferenceError: orly is not defined`

Comment: @PaulS. Correct! I retract my previous comments...

Comment: Thank you @bfavaretto and PaulS , can you suggest a code that will do a similar condition to what I suggested ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **create** an error in *JavaScript* you have to [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) something, which can be an [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), a [specific type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Error_types) of *Error*, or any *Object* or *String*.

```
function five_is_bad(x) {
    if (x===5) {
        // `x` should never be 5! Throw an error!
        throw new RangeError('Input was 5!');
    }
    return x;
}

console.log('a');
try {
    console.log('b');
    five_is_bad(5); // error thrown in this function so this 
                    // line causes entry into catch
    console.log('c'); // this line doesn't execute if exception in `five_is_bad`
} catch (ex) {
    // this only happens if there was an exception in the `try`
    console.log('in catch with', ex, '[' + ex.message + ']');
} finally {
    // this happens either way
    console.log('d');
}
console.log('e');
/*
a
b
in catch with RangeError {} [Input was 5!]
d
e
*/
```

Comment: Again, I think you understood the OP better than I did. +1

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
function exceptionhandler() {
    try {
        if (x===5) {
            // do something  
        }
    } catch(ex) {
        throw new Error("Boo! " + ex.message)
    }
}
```